# NSManagedObjectContext save appearing to lose objects

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm creating an object with the following code:

```
 +(Checkin *) newCheckinWithId:(NSString*) checkinID forVenueId:(NSString *)venueId
{
    NSManagedObjectContext * context = [[AppDelegate sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
    Checkin *ret = (Checkin *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Checkin" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    ret.checkinID = checkinID;
    ret.forVenueID = venueId;
    ret.date = [NSDate date];
    NSError * error;
    if(![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving!!!!!: %@", error.userInfo);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

and there is no error, but after save I never se any record of that object again.

Running the debugger over this function I see that it has 1 object in unprocessedInserts and after save 0 objects in all internal sets in the context (i'm not sure if thats expected or not.

Here is the code I use to create my store + managed object context (I use 1 context for everything) Its basically all from a stack overflow post I found

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    //NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
    //__managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    //NSArray *testArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLsForResourcesWithExtension:@"momd"subdirectory:nil];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Model" ofType:@"momd"];

    if( !path ) path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Model" ofType:@"mom"];

    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    //__managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if((_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

    // Set up iCloud in another thread:

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you MUST change this variable:
        NSString *iCloudEnabledAppID = @"[MY APP ID]";

        // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you should change this variable:
        NSString *dataFileName = @"foursquareaugmentation.sqlite";

        // ** Note: For basic usage you shouldn't need to change anything else

        NSString *iCloudDataDirectoryName = @"Data.nosync";
        NSString *iCloudLogsDirectoryName = @"Logs";
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *localStore = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];
        NSURL *iCloud = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

        if (iCloud) {

            NSLog(@"iCloud is working");

            NSURL *iCloudLogsPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudLogsDirectoryName]];

            NSLog(@"iCloudEnabledAppID = %@",iCloudEnabledAppID);
            NSLog(@"dataFileName = %@", dataFileName);
            NSLog(@"iCloudDataDirectoryName = %@", iCloudDataDirectoryName);
            NSLog(@"iCloudLogsDirectoryName = %@", iCloudLogsDirectoryName);
            NSLog(@"iCloud = %@", iCloud);
            NSLog(@"iCloudLogsPath = %@", iCloudLogsPath);

            if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]] == NO) {
                NSError *fileSystemError;
                [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                       withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                        attributes:nil
                                             error:&fileSystemError];
                if(fileSystemError != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Error creating database directory %@", fileSystemError);
                }
            }

            NSString *iCloudData = [[[iCloud path]
                                     stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];

            NSLog(@"iCloudData = %@", iCloudData);

            NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:iCloudEnabledAppID            forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
            [options setObject:iCloudLogsPath                forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey];

            [psc lock];
            NSError *error;

            [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                              configuration:nil
                                        URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:iCloudData]
                                    options:options
                                      error:&error];

            if( error )
            {
                NSLog(@"Error adding persistent store %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

                // comment in this line while debugging if get "Can't find model for source store" error in addPersistentStoreWithType.
                // it means the sqlite database doesn't match the new model and needs to be created from scratch.
                // this happens if you change the xcdatamodel instead of creating a new one under Xcode->Editor->Add Model Version...
                // CoreData can only automatically migrate if there is a new model version (it can't migrate if the model simply changes, because it can't see the difference between the two models).
                // be sure to back up the database if needed, because all data will be lost.
                //[fileManager removeItemAtPath:iCloudData error:&error];

                /*// this is another way to verify the hashes for the database's model to make sure they match one of the entries in the momd directory's VersionInfo.plist
                 NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:iCloudData] error:&error];

                 if( !sourceMetadata )
                 NSLog(@"sourceMetadata is nil");
                 else
                 NSLog(@"sourceMetadata is %@", sourceMetadata);*/
            }

            [psc unlock];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"iCloud is NOT working - using a local store");
            NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];

            [psc lock];
            NSError *error;

            [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                              configuration:nil
                                        URL:localStore
                                    options:options
                                      error:nil];

            if( error )
                NSLog(@"Error adding persistent store %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            [psc unlock];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomethingChanged" object:self userInfo:nil];
        });
    });

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;   
}

/*
 Returns the managed object context for the application.
 If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

I've been working on this for quiet a while and am out of things to try so any helps or debug steps would be greatly appreciated. (also it doesn't work on icloud or local)

Maybe i'm fetching wrong and thats why I'm not getting objects. Here is my fetch:

```
+(NSArray *) checkinsForVenue:(NSString *) venueID
{
    NSManagedObjectContext * context = [[AppDelegate sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Checkin" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = entity;

    //NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(forVenueID = %@)", venueID];
    //request.predicate = predicate;

    NSError *error;
    NSArray * ret = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if(ret == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

EDIT: I was asking the wrong question. Saving is working fetching is not. Still can't figure out what is wrong with my fetch.

Comment: Also everything I can think of seems normal  Checkin *ret = (Checkin *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Checkin" inManagedObjectContext:context]; returns a good object; context is not nil, etc not sure what else to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked to see if it's actually being persisted to sqlite?

Your app should be in `~Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications`.  You'll have to find which app folder is yours (they're all named by UUIDS), and then look in the `Documents` folder for the sqlite file. In your code, that'd be `foursquareaugmentation.sqlite`.

Open a Terminal window in that directory and fire up `sqlite3 foursquareaugmentation.sqlite` to start querying the database.

You should find a table named `ZCHECKIN` (if you have an managed object class named `Checkin`), and every time you save the context, it should be adding to that table.

So running `select * from zcheckin;` after each save should show you one more row added to that table.

If that's not happening, something's going wrong in the `save` operation.  If it's in the database table, then it's something in your code that's losing a reference to the object, setting it to `nil` somewhere, or something like that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx for the start! I did that and found 1 entry in the table, however there should be at least 20 in there. So it must be working once then failing or something.

In the code however I never see any, even this 1 that is actually there

Comment: Ah Wait!!! I did the 20 on my actual phone, yes it is getting in the DB when I save, must be something wrong with the fletch then? The fetch still returns 0 rows.

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried using the debugger to inspect the NSArray coming back from your fetch? You can use the left-hand pane of the debugger to expand the contents of the array and see how many objects are in it... or right-click it and print the contents.  

I'd probably cut out the iCloud code just to simplify the problem, then try banging a few rows into Core Data on the simulator and retrieving them from there.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should create two contexts both in `create` and `fetch`. This will make the Core Data confused, and will not fetch the newest object from the managed objects, although after `insert new object successfully`.

So I suggest that, you should pass the context between two methods. At least, it works for me.